# Joining to child data which may or may not have data for each record in parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have table 1 and table2.
In table we have basic participant information.

In table 2 we will have special info of participant (All the participants may not have the special info so they don't have record in table 2).

Now I want to join the two tables based on participantid, am able to get only the info if we have data in both tables but I need all the participant info who don't have special info.

Comment: Use `left join` instead of `join` or `inner join`

Comment: Please show the query that you ran.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Comment: @jarlh Sorry Updated :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use join here(left outer join or right outer join)

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.Column=tbl2.Column
```